# How many Son'a were left after Star Trek: Insurrection?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-insurrection

In the film *Star Trek: Insurrection*, the main antagonists are the Son'a, a species that is an offshoot of the Ba'ku species.

Apparently, there weren't too many Son'a that left the Ba'ku. During the events of *Star Trek: Insurrection*, it appeared to me that most of the So'na were either killed or returned to the Ba'ku.

However, during the final season of *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, either Weyoun or the Female Changeling (I forget which) mention receiving help from the So'na in their fight against the Federation. I assumed that the amount of So'na that initially left the Ba'ku was somewhat small, and that they didn't reproduce that much, if at all.

Am I incorrect in my assumption? How many So'na were left to roam the galaxy after *Star Trek: Insurrection*?

Comment: The Son'a and the Ba'ku were not separate species.  Some of the Son'a were children of some of the Ba'ku.  It would take a vast amount of genetic engineering to make someone's child a member of a biologically different species.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The events of *Insurrection* take place just prior to the end of the Dominion War, not after the war like you are thinking of.  The Son'a had plenty of time and resources to help the Dominion before being taken down in *Insurrection*.

From Memory Alpha: [Timeline of *Star Trek*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Star_Trek):

> 2369–2375
>   - The events of [Star Trek: Deep Space Nine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine) .
>
> 2373–2375
>   - The Dominion War is fought
>
> 2375
>   - The events of [Star Trek: Insurrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection). **Dialogue in this film and in the DS9 finale ["What You Leave Behind"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind) place the chronology of this film as during that episode, after the final battle of the war but before the treaty signing ceremony**. Most notable in the film is Worf's ability to leave the station to join the Enterprise, as well as a line about Federation diplomats being involved in Dominion negotiations, and the Federation's willingness to work with **the Son'a, who are established as a Dominion ally during the war**.